# Detect if mobile device supports J2ME WMA

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, wma

Is it possible to detect if the mobile device supports J2ME WMA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code,

```
public static boolean isWMAPresent(){
    try {
        Class.forName(
               "javax.wireless.messaging.MessageConnection" );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception e ){
        return false;
    }
}
```

For more info see this article, [J2ME Optional Packages.](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/optional/)

Answer (score 1):

@Bharath's answer is a good one.

Alternative is to check for the existence of SMSC system property as follows:

```
public static boolean isWMAPresent() {
    return System.getProperty("wireless.messaging.sms.smsc") != null;
}
```

You can also check to see if MMS is supported by checking for MMS property:

```
public static boolean isWMAPresent() {
    return System.getProperty("wireless.messaging.mms.mmsc") != null;
}
```